# How to change usb drive's "Disk model", as shown in fdisk -l?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, disk, usb-drive, fdisk

## Info

I have two USB flash drives. Both are "SanDisk Cruzer Blade"s. One is 8GB, the other is 64GB.

`fdisk -l` (8GB):

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 7.45 GiB, 8004304896 bytes, 15633408 sectors
Disk model: Cruzer Blade    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xcf0c9ad9
```

`fdisk -l` (64GB):

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 57.33 GiB, 61555605504 bytes, 120225792 sectors
Disk model: Cruzer Blade    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 3E29E0CB-68C6-3B47-9861-B92FC65CA0D6
```

## Problem

The "Disk model" values of both are "Cruzer Blade". Both have this name in my motherboard's boot menu, so I can't distinguish between the two when choosing a disk to boot from.

## Questions

- Can "Disk model" be changed?
- If so, how?

I'd like to name 8GB "sandisk-8gb-1" and 64GB "sandisk-64gb-1".

## My research

- Every thread I find shows either how to change the partitions' or the filesystems' labels.

I can't find anything that shows how to change the disk model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disk model can't be changed, it's reported by the device firmware, `fdisk` simply reads it from `/sys/block/sdX/device/model`.

Filesystem labels and partition names (with GPT) are unfortunately only things you can change, but that's not going to help you when booting.

Answer (score 0):

Affix a physical label to your USB's and write the size/contents on it.

This is convenient even when you have many USB's of different makes.